# How to make animate.css work in rails? As animate-rails is not working on heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, animate.css

animate-rails is not working on **heroku**, but working on local. Coffeescript is working on heroku production though.

rails version: **Rails 6.1.4.1**
ruby version: **ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [arm64-darwin20]**

Below is the code in the respective files:

**Gemfile** -> `gem "animate-rails"`

**application.css.scss** ->  `*= require animate`

**application.js** -> `import 'animate.css/animate'`

**package.json** -> `"animate.css": "^4.1.1"`

**production.rb** -> `config.assets.compile = false`

**html file** -> `.nav-item.animate__animated.fadeIn.animate__slower.animate__delay-2s Sample Text`

**application.html.slim**

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
```

**environment.js**

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const coffee = require('./loaders/coffee')
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)
environment.loaders.prepend('coffee', coffee)
module.exports = environment
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SCSS, can you try modifying your `application.css.scss` file:

```
@import 'animate';
```

Comment: Tried using `@import 'animate';` in `appliclation.css.scss`, no luck

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with your `application.scss` file name, it shouldn't be .css.scss. The extension should only be .scss.

Also, you can try running `./bin/webpack` in your production environment if you are using webpacker (which comes standard in Rails 6).

Comment: Tried changing the exitension to only `.scss`, and ran `./bin/webpack`, it still won't work :/

Comment: Did you precompile your assets? RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile

Comment: Yes, tried the same, yet it won't work